# Color add to preset (navbar) in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Cruz Control</a>
        </div>
```

I want to add color to my button, I use javascript throughout my script.

Please,
   &
Thank you.

Comment: add `style="background-color:#000088"` to the button tag to change its color of to blue, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap you can add color like this.

`$('button').addClass('bg-white');  //if you want white`

try this.

Comment: why not add the `bg-white` directly to the button class list?

Comment: He want to add button color at javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use pure javascript:

For all buttons in document:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.color= 'red';
}
```

If you want to affect only elements with specific class, then:

```
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName('your-class')

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color= 'red';
}
```

If you want to affect only one element, give it some id, then:

```
document.getElementById('yourId').style.color= 'red';
```

or if you are ok with using jQuery, then:

```
$('button').css('color', 'green');
```